# can we combine the code of Angular directive and factory?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-filters

I have a Angular directive which looks like this:

```
.directive('datefilter', function (dateFilter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from view format to model format
                return new Date(data); //converted
            });

            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from model format to view format
                return new Date(data); //converted
            });
        }
    }
})
```

This directive i am using on text field like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="someModelName" datefilter uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}">
```

**Now**

I have this Angular filter:

```
.filter('datefilterfilter', function (dateFilter) {
        return function (value, format) {
            return dateFilter(new Date(value), format);
        };
    });
```

This filter i am using like this:

```
<b> {{someModelNAme | datefilterfilter: format}} </b>
```

Ultimately both directive and filter doing same job but this directive require `ng-model` so i can't apply it to `<b>` tag because it doesn't have any `ng-model`. Is there any way to combine both `directive` and `filter` which will work for both element (for `text filed` and `<b>` tag )?

Comment: you want the Text in the textbox to be **Bold** ??

Comment: No, both `directive` and `filter` returning `new Date()` i want to write the code once.

Comment: when your directive returns a `new Date()` what is the purpose of having filter?

Comment: From database i am getting JavaScript `Date()` Object, but it is in `string` format so for display i need to convert it to `new Date()`

Comment: Your database returns a string or Date() object ?? what is your DB and service written in??

Answer (score 1):

You can use any filter in your directive by injecting the `$filter` service:

```
.directive('datefilter', ["$filter", function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from view format to model format
                return $filter("datefilterfilter")(data); //converted
            });

            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from model format to view format
                return $filter("datefilterfilter")(data); //converted
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Approach is correct but sounds wrong to have same operation for `$parsers` and `$formatters`...

Comment: Of course you can extract it in one function or do it differently in both, but that was not the question of the OP.